# testing ajax autocomplete with Rspec and Capybara, Mysql transaction

Tags: mysql, ajax, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to have a reliable testing of my ajax.

I'm using Rspec tests and capybara with selenium driver. This is the testcase I'm currently looking at:

```
  it "has autocomplete on the category field", js: true do
    categories = create_list :category, 5
    category = categories.first

    visit root_path

    fill_in 'token-input-categories', with: category.name
    choose_autocomplete_result "category.name", "#to_contact_name"
  end
```

at the `fill_in` command the test server successfully receives the ajax call asking for the autocomplete data, but because that's a separate thread, and the current test is in a transaction, the DB is seen empty, and there's no resulting data.

I've seen [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup) that I could change the default behaviour to `truncate`, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.livinginthepast.org/2013/11/24/today-we-went-to-the-bad-place.html) article on how to configure the truncation only for the `js: true` tests, the only difference was that the `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` line rises an error, which appears to be because the `use_transactional_fixtures` has changed its inheritance chain. Because that's the default anyway, I just removed the line.